# How can I make one row out of three rows in Java?

Tags: java, format, substring, row

I have a css file with this type of text in :

```
.fa-glass:before {
 content: "\f000";
}
.fa-music:before {
 content: "\f001";
}
.fa-search:before {
content: "\f002";
}
```

I want fo format the text so it would return  something like :

```
GLASS(f000),
MUSIC(f001),
SEARCH(f0002)
```

I did some research and found a lot of code on SO and tried the following

```
   String result = cssFile.substring(cssFile.indexOf("-") + 1, cssFile.indexOf(":b") +1);
```

And got this result :

```
GLASS:

MUSIC:

SEARCH:
```

I neither want the ":" after the name, nor the empty rows. I know why it return like this though. It´s because in the source file the text inside  {}  and the  brackets themselfs expands on 3 rows. Because when I remove the +1 I get exception: String index out of range: -1.
Is there a way with java to move the second curly bracket and the text inside the curly brackets to the first row? I don´t want to do it manually since there are more tan 1000 entries.
Thanks

Comment: If you get an index exception when you remove the `+1`, that must mean that `indexOf()` is returning `-1` (string not found). That means you are currently getting `cssFile.substring(0, 0)`, which is an empty string. I think you need to surround your code with something that checks for this case and doesn't produce a result when the substring isn't found. Without a proper context for your line of code, I can't really specify.

Comment: @khelwood I tried to manually set the curly barckets on the first row for the first 5 entries or so and I did not get the error anymore. The output was the wanted one. I also tried to remove empty spaces but the code did not do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code achieves the same. Code is not optimal since I need to rush. Kindly optimize through usage of Stringbuffers and whatever you feel fit where ever applicable.

```
File f=new File("test.css");
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        String ln;
        StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
        while((ln=br.readLine())!=null){
            sb.append(ln);
        }
        String[] sections=sb.toString().split("}");
        for(String st:sections){
            String temp=st.substring(st.indexOf("-")+1, st.indexOf(":")).toUpperCase()+"("+st.substring(st.indexOf("\\")+1, st.indexOf("\";"))+")";
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
```

OUTPUT :

GLASS(f000)
MUSIC(f001)
SEARCH(f002)

Comment: Welcome ! But please optimize it. Using "+" multiple times to concatenate string can lead to severe memory issues. Kindly use StringBuffer or StringBuilder. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your expression doesn't match when the line does not contain either the character "-" nor the character ":".

That's the case of your empty lines:

- Line `.fa-glass:before {`: Contains ":" and "-" so it produces: `glass:`
- Line `content: "\f000";` does not contains ":" so your code produce  an empty string (`cssFile.substring(0, 0)=""`)

And so on.

I've code a simple test that does what you want:

```
@Test
public void testConcat() throws Exception {

    /*
     * String that simulates a file with this content:
     * .fa-glass:before {
     *    content: "\f000";
     * }
     * .fa-music:before {
     *    content: "\f001";
     * }
     * .fa-search:before {
     *    content: "\f002";
     * }
     */
    String cssFile = ".fa-glass:before {\n content: \"\\f000\";\n}\n.fa-music:before {\n content: \"\\f001\";\n}\n.fa-search:before {\ncontent: \"\\f002\";}";

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(cssFile));

    String line = null;
    String name = null;
    String value = null;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    while( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if(line.contains(".fa-")) {
            name = line.substring(line.indexOf(".fa-") + 4, line.indexOf(":")).toUpperCase();
        } else if(line.contains(";")){
            value = line.substring(line.indexOf(": \"") + 3, line.lastIndexOf("\""));
            result.append(String.format("%s(%s)\n", name, value));
        }
    }

    /*
     * It will print:
     * GLASS(\f000)
     * MUSIC(\f001)
     * SEARCH(\f002)
     */
    System.out.println(result.toString());

    assertThat(result.toString()).isEqualTo("GLASS(\\f000)\nMUSIC(\\f001)\nSEARCH(\\f002)\n");
}
```

Comment: hey there, thanks again. You helped me earlier today as well. You are right again. I just had a look at ma file and I have entries that end after ":before," and I would  of gotten an error even if I had the curly brackets on one row. I will try to figure out how to use your code with a .css String. In my original code I read a css file from my PC.  like this   ´public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
   FileReader fr = new FileReader("D:\\eclipse\\font-awesome.css");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    String cssFile = null;
´

Comment: just replace my creation of `BufferedReader` by your own implementation. You can reuse the rest of the code (all the code behind `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(cssFile));`)

Comment: Ok, so I tried that and I got 10 entries formated the way I wanted but it´s a good start and I appreciate your help a lot. I will play arund with the code ad see what I get

Answer (score 0):

If you have notepad++ (or any text editor that can "replace all" based on a pattern - I've used notepad++ with the 'Extended' Search Mode selected for this - you can make the change pretty quick.

First time, find {\r\n, replace with empty string.
Second time, find \r\n}, replace with empty string.

End result is

```
.fa-glass:before  content: "\f000";
.fa-music:before  content: "\f001";
.fa-search:before content: "\f002";
```

If you want the curly braces to remain, then just change the 'replace with' portion during replacement

Comment: you mean to change it in notepad++ or in Java? I just tried it in notepad ++ and found no occurances.

Comment: Yes, notepad++. Make sure you have the "Extend mode" radio button selected. It's also possible some of the whitespace characters are different in your file compared to copied & pasted from this question